# Manhwa where the MC has a PC to create Dungeons and gets to choose the difficulty of the Dungeons

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, martial-arts

I remember that he first talks about his 40 yo uncle, that he is adventurous and used to talk with him about that stuff. Later he lost touch with him, but suddenly gets a package containing a PC system to set up Dungeons (it has a 7 day cool-down after each Dungeon completion)

His uncle warns him that he absolutely mustn't pick anything higher than easy for his first Dungeons.

The first Dungeon is a Cave where he encounters Kobolds and they were crazy about their candles (you get why I couldn't forget that pun) and they even drop some Gold from time to time.

Creatures did not reset as far as I remember.

He sells the Gold and the Staff guessed that he might have found a Goldmine and talks his boss into taking action, which leads them towards a fight with him (the staff named it Koboldgold).

He learns some martial arts during his 3rd/4th dungeon where he gets to "summon" a person to help him or maybe the person was part of his mission for this dungeon -- I forgot about the specifics.

The MC concludes the fight with the boss and ended up in a dojo where he shows off his "real martial arts" and the people go crazy about the real stuff.

It had around 65 Chapters at that point but went for a minor break and so I bookmarked it but my PC crashed and I lost that precious fun story.

Oh, I forgot to add that he changed his appearance to a silver-haired, anime-like, super-beauty before he went to that dojo.

Dungeons I can remember:

**Kobold Cave** 
Faced Kobolds and Koboldchief with a magical Candle - A hidden Spidercave aswell.

**Crypt** 
He solves a grudge where he kills a sidecasted lover that missuses necromancy for revenge at the end he got himself a follower. He used the summon skill to get some dogs and the strongest ended up being his pet but he left the dungeon while forgetting about him and resents himself for it.

**Bandit Fort** 
He meets/summons a martial artist and they fight the camps together. They decide to divide the loot by camps. The Artist gets 2 specific camps, and the MC gets the loot of the other two. They fight 4 powerful old Martial artists where he uses a handgun as well.

Later they free some people from a Prison but they only have one key - there are three doors to open. One with a fortuneteller, another with a woman that offers her body, and the last held a withered Skeleton with unknown loot.

He opens the door of the old Fortuneteller and gets to loot the Skeleton later on, but I think he used some ability he gained.

The main camp was protected by some guy with a big lion, and they defeated them as well.

At the end he got a coin or something to re-summon the martial artist that helped him during the mission/dungeon)

Comment: Could this be The Gamer? It seems to resemble some aspects of the story you're mentioning, but not all of them.

Comment: Is he aware of his stats in an RPG-like fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirmed on [the Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/manhwa/comments/qahkgu/looking_formanhwa_where_mc_gets_to_use_a_pc_to/), that this is ["There's An Instance Dungeon In My Living Room"](https://www.webnovel.com/book/there%27s-an-instance-dungeon-in-my-living-room_16707930705922105).

> One morning, Chu Ge woke up to find that the entrance to an Instance Dungeon had appeared in his living room.
>
> Holy cr*p! What in the world was going on? Even if I were an experienced gamer, if you want me to challenge an Instance Dungeon for real... It's still impossible for me!

Poking into the story, it opens with Chu Ge talking to his uncle, Xie Tiankong, and mentioning how his uncle talked about many amazing adventures which could not plausibly happened since they involve fantastical realms. The second chapter has the mysterious package delivered and the third chapter has him finding that it's the mysterious PC that allows him to create a dungeon to adventure in, where it's also suggested that he start at "Noob" difficulty.

Comment: Thank you very much! Its just awesome how fast you solved a problem i´ve been struggling with for almost two years

Comment: No worries. All I did was monitor the Reddit topic.